# a href don't work with ng-repeat in my case

Tags: javascript, angularjs

demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/ktnDiUSA7eU7DNkIbTqo

```
   <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="thread in data">
           <a href="{{thead.url}}" target="_blank">
                {{thread.title}}
           </a>
       </li>
   </ul>
```

I got my json like this

```
$scope.data = [
{
    "title": " 'Aku kecewa, tiada harapan kalahkan DAP'",
    "desc": "BACKER QUITS ?",
    "starter": "rhoyo",
    "replies": " 23 ",
    "url": "https://forum.lowyat.net/Kopitiam/topic/3235530"
},
{
    "title": " Angry China launches war against terror ",
    "desc": "",
    "starter": "rivost",
    "replies": " 6 ",
    "url": "https://forum.lowyat.net/Kopitiam/topic/3235746"
}
```

];

why when I do `{{thread.url}}` it did print out the direct url?

Comment: typo. missing "r" in thread `<a href="{{thead.url}}" target="_blank">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you should fix typo `thread.url` instead of `thead.url`

Then replace `href` attribute with `ng-href`

```
<a ng-href="{{thread.url}}" target="_blank">
    {{thread.title}}
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Angular's ngHref directive. Simply replace `href` with `ng-href`.

Take a look here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref